# Getting an Error while using star import in Java while executing maven install

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, compilation

[image: Only Delta in Java class file which in under src/main/tests]

I am getting an error while executing `mvn clean install -DskipTests`:

```
[66,8] error: cannot access WorkflowType
```

WorkflowType is an enum in adminpackage as seen on left side of the image. There is no compile time error reported by IntelliJ. There is no other change in whole project.

**Import Statements on right side causes mvn build to fail but the left side import statements work fine and build gets succesful.**

P.S. These 'white-outs' import are from another library and included as a dependency. I am not able to understand why is this happening.

Comment: Are you certain those import statements are relevant? The error is pointing to line 66 character 8, your screenshot does not seem to include a line 66.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, these are the ONLY difference in the whole file. Line 66 is nothing but a use of enum WorkFlowType : WorkflowType workflowType = WorkflowType.CREATE_NEW;